# Call filling method with `@TargetMapping` from parent's mapping method

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a scenario where I need to use the source's parent to resolve few fields, as well as the source itself, as well as have source create a target child too. I will explain:

```
class SourceResponse {
   List<SourceRecord> results;
}

class SourceRecord {
   String status;
   SourceProperty property;
}

class SourceProperty {
   String address;
   Double latitude;...(100+ fields)
}
```

The target look like this:

```
class TargetResponse {
   List<TargetProperty> results;
}

class TargetProperty {
   FetchDetail fetchDetail;
   
   String address;
   Double latitude; ... those same 100+fields
}

class FetchDetail {
   String status;
}
```

If I write this mapping :

```
1. TargetResponse map(SourceResponse val);

2. List<TargetProperty> map (List<SourceRecord> val);

   @Mapping(target = "address", ignore = true)
   @Mapping(target = "latitude", ignore = true)
   ...
   @Mapping(source = ".", target = "fetchDetail")
3. TargetProperty map(SourceRecord val);

   @Mapping(source = "status", target = "status")
4. FetchDetail map(SourceRecord val);

5. void map(@MappingTarget TargetProperty property, SourceProperty val);
```

How do I make (5) to be called by (3)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an update mapping here.
You can just specify the mappings like this at (3):

```java
@Mapping(target = ".", source = "property") // handles the 100 fields
@Mapping(target = "fetchDetail", source = ".") // handles the status
TargetProperty map(SourceRecord val);
```

The complete class can look something like this:

```java
@Mapper
interface ResponseMapper {

    TargetResponse map(SourceResponse val);

    @Mapping(target = ".", source = "property")
    @Mapping(target = "fetchDetail", source = ".")
    TargetProperty map(SourceRecord val);
}
```

This will generate something like this:

```java
    @Override
    public TargetResponse map(SourceResponse val) {
        if ( val == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        TargetResponse targetResponse = new TargetResponse();

        targetResponse.setResults( sourceRecordListToTargetPropertyList( val.getResults() ) );

        return targetResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public TargetProperty map(SourceRecord val) {
        if ( val == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        TargetProperty targetProperty = new TargetProperty();

        targetProperty.setFetchDetail( sourceRecordToFetchDetail( val ) );
        targetProperty.setAddress( valPropertyAddress( val ) );
        targetProperty.setLatitude( valPropertyLatitude( val ) );

        return targetProperty;
    }

    protected List<TargetProperty> sourceRecordListToTargetPropertyList(List<SourceRecord> list) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<TargetProperty> list1 = new ArrayList<TargetProperty>( list.size() );
        for ( SourceRecord sourceRecord : list ) {
            list1.add( map( sourceRecord ) );
        }

        return list1;
    }

    protected FetchDetail sourceRecordToFetchDetail(SourceRecord sourceRecord) {
        if ( sourceRecord == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        FetchDetail fetchDetail = new FetchDetail();

        fetchDetail.setStatus( sourceRecord.getStatus() );

        return fetchDetail;
    }

    private String valPropertyAddress(SourceRecord sourceRecord) {
        if ( sourceRecord == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        SourceProperty property = sourceRecord.getProperty();
        if ( property == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        String address = property.getAddress();
        if ( address == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return address;
    }

    private Double valPropertyLatitude(SourceRecord sourceRecord) {
        if ( sourceRecord == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        SourceProperty property = sourceRecord.getProperty();
        if ( property == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Double latitude = property.getLatitude();
        if ( latitude == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return latitude;
    }
```

This does generate a lot of unnecessary null-checks for the mapping with source `property`. But all the required functionality is there.